# Screen Resolution Issue - Grid Cut Off on Only Certain Resolutions

Tags: wpf

I have a fixed layout and would like my app to look the same on all machines, regardless of screen size or resolution. While testing my app with the Simulator, I've found that my layout is cut off on different resolution.

```
<Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="1024" Height="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

On the resolutions specified above, the last column is cut off. The rows all render without any problems. I am wondering if someone could please give me some insight as to what I may be able to do in order to get my app to look the same on all screen sizes and resolutions. I would prefer to have the Stretch property set to either Uniform or UniformToFill.